# "Sorry, Having Trouble Accessing the Skill..." - but no obvious reason

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

[image]I developed a skill but keeping getting this error message - why, is not obvious to me.  Here is a short video of the experience 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jouc8587kjef66z/IMG_1331.mp4?dl=0

and and below is the part of the code where I get the error.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to spot the closing semicolon (;) at the end of that line.  Perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: sorry, just added another image that shows the closing semicolon, etc.

Comment: Have you tried string concatenation instead of mutating the original string...for instance:

speechOutput = "This " + " is " + " a " + " test.";

Comment: No, haven't tried this, but since at least 1 or minutes of talk before this line worked fine, it's not clear why this one line needs string concatenation. Is there a reason why it would be needed when it's not needed before.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Have you tried remove that specific line and testing.  That should help narrow it down.

Comment: I just did that..removed the part of that line where the problem begins.  Now, it still throws an error when it gets to the end of the (now shortened) line.  Strange.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are you using the Java library?

Comment: it's written is node.js  I just took that line completely out and now it gets the error in the same place...honestly, this is looking like Alexa has only a certain amount of words and/or time that it can speak and then it bombs out.

Comment: That may be true.  Try adding more text to the first line and comment the rest out.  See if it will break.  For example:

speechOutput = "My milkshake brings all the boys to the hard I could teach you but I'd have to charge " + 

"My milkshake brings all the boys to the hard I could teach you but I'd have to charge " + 
"My milkshake brings all the boys to the hard I could teach you but I'd have to charge " + 
"My milkshake brings all the boys to the hard I could teach you but I'd have to charge ";

Comment: I just read through some documentation and it states the outputSpeech response is limited to 8000 characters. Link docs.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference

Comment: Ok..I did that and there was no problem..except now Alexa only reads part of that  speechOutput - so it's cutting it off but not throwing an error.

Comment: Hi Wifibrian..thanks for finding this, I'm pretty sure this is the cause of my problems...will change to accommodate that restriction.